# How to Populate a Kivy Tree View from an sqlite Table

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

### What I Have

I have an sqlite database with two tables.  The first has 42 items with fields such as typeID, typeName, description, maxPrice, and groupID, of which there are 4 different groupIDs.  Then there are another 6 or so fields that are needed for other calculations later on but are not needed for the Tree View.  The second has a similar construction with each item having typeID, groupID, typeName, description, price, and then 8 additional fields.  The key point is that both tables have items lumped together into groups.

### What I Want

I want to populate a [kivy Tree View](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html) from each of these tables.  The groupID fields should serve as parents and all the typeIDs that have that groupID should be children.  I could just hard code this in but my data can change (and it would be a pain in the neck to type them all out) so I'd like to keep this dynamic so that should my tables update I could just automatically re-make the Tree Views.

### Big Picture

My goal is for the user to be able to select one item from the Tree View that is crafted from the first table and then many items (including duplicates of a particular item) from the Tree View that is crafted from the second table.  The way I'm currently thinking of doing this is that when the user selects an item from the first Tree View it shows up at the top of some other widget and then when the user selects an item from the second Tree View it shows up below that item from the first along with a quantity counter that the user can change.  The limit is that the total price of all items from Tree View 2 must not exceed the maxPrice for the selected item from Tree View 1.

A rough example would look like this:

```
Item 3 from Tree View 1 maxPrice 10000
Item 1 from Tree View 2 price 1000 Qty 2
Item 3 from Tree View 2 price 3000 Qty 1
Item 4 from Tree View 2 price 500 Qty 4
Item 9 from Tree View 2 price 1000 Qty 2
price remaining 1000
```

In this example price is (2*1000)+(1*3000)+(4*500)+(2*1000)=9000 which is under the maxPrice for item 3 from Tree View 1 which is 10000 and thus this is OK.  If, for example, the user tried to now change Qty of Item 3 from Tree View 2 to 2 it should show price remaining of -2000 (and perhaps change this to red or something so that it stands out.)

Once I get the two Tree Views up and running, I think I can figure out how to get the rest to work (or I'll be posting another question!)  I just wanted to provide this 'big picture' look at my end goal to help give some context for my question.

Answer (score 2):

I have been fighting with this for hours now and finally got something that roughly works!  I'd still love to hear how this could be streamlined.  Also, it's fairly clumsy on the screen with big buttons and no scroll bar (so when you open up a few of the subtrees the tree goes off the bottom of your screen and you can't reach it.)  Oh, and this is jsut for the 2nd of the two Tree Views I wanted to make, but it's the harder one so the other should be easy to make from this.  With those disclaimers aside, here's the code:

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import sqlite3
import os

POSdb = "C:\Users\User\Path\To\My\Database.db"

class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    pass

modGroups = []
modItems = []
modDict = dict()
modDictUnique = dict()

def populate_tree_view(tv):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(POSdb)
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select * from ModuleTable')
    r = c.fetchall()
    for entry in r:
        modGroups.append(entry['groupID'])
        modItems.append(entry['typeName'])
    modDict = zip(modGroups, modItems)
    for k, v in modDict:
        if k not in modDictUnique:
            modDictUnique[k] = [v]
        else:
            modDictUnique[k].append(v)
    sortedGroups = modDictUnique.keys()
    sortedGroups.sort()
    #print modItems
    #print modDictUnique
    n = tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='POS Mods', is_open=True))
    for group in sortedGroups:
        g = tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='%s' % group), n)
        for item in modDictUnique[group]:
            tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(text='%s' % item), g)


class POSFM(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(POSFM, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Tree One'),
                      hide_root=True,
                      indent_level=4)

        populate_tree_view(tv)

        self.add_widget(tv)


class POSFMApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return POSFM()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    POSFMApp(width=800).run()
```